# Connect two arrays in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have two arrays - one integer(title of books) and one string(prices of books).
I don't know how to connect the name of each book with it's price.
I'm using a ComboBox to select the title of the book..and i want it's price to be displayed in a Label.

Example:
 Book(0) = "Pride and Prejudice"
 Book(1) = "To kill a Mockingbird"

Price(0) = 10.5
 Price(1) = 11.2

Comment: What UI technology are you using?

Comment: They seem to share the same index in the arrays, you can use that. Although I would go with @Plutonix solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class instead to connect related things:

```
Class Book
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Author As String
    Public Property Publisher As String
    Public Property ISBN As String       
    Public Property RetailPrice As Decimal

    Public Overrrides Function ToString As String
        Return Title
    End Function
End Class
```

Then a List or Dictionary to store them:

```
Friend _Books As New List(Of Book)
Dim B as New Book
With B
    .Title = "Pride and Prejudice"
    ' etc
End With
_Books.Add(B)
```

The properties help organize the data and make the code more readable.  The `ToString` override allows you to add Book Objects to a `ListBox`, `ComboBox` or edit them in a `CollectionEditor` and display something friendly like a `Name` property might.

Otherwise use a 2 dimensional array; very old school though

```
Book(0)(0) = "Pride and Prejudice"
Book(0)(1) = "11.30"
```

Answer (score 0):

u can start simply like that

```
Dim dicBooks As New Dictionary(Of String, Decimal) From {{"Pride and Prejudice", 10.5}, {"To kill a Mockingbird", 11.2}}

        ComboBox1.DataSource = dicBooks.ToArray()
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"
```

moreover @Plutonix's code too